# array of questions on pointers, double pointers, malloc, realloc and new (to set the record straight)

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory-management

I'm catching up on pointers. I wrote down a few lines of code to test the different ways I could dynamically allocate a 2d array (posted at the bottom)

My questions are the following:

1. Should I use malloc in c++, or new? If I use new, can I still use realloc?
2. When should I use realloc? What are the implications of using it in terms of performance and bugs?
3. Out of the examples bellow, which objectNew version should I use? If the answer depends on the application, what are does it depend on?

Many thanks,
Matt

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct myObject
{
    int data;
    myObject(int i)
    {
        data = i;
    }
    myObject()
    {
        data = 0;
    }

};

int main(){
    int r = 7;
    int c = 6;

    printf("Objects using NEW===============================\n");
    //notice the triple pointer being assigned a new double pointer array
    myObject*** objectNew = new myObject** [r];

    for(int i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        //objectNew is a 1D array of double pointers, however if we assign another layer of pointers, it becomes a 2D array of pointers to myObject
        objectNew[i] = new myObject* [c];
        for(int j=0;j<c;j++){
            objectNew[i][j] = new myObject(10*i+j);
            //notice that we dereference data (->)
            printf("objectNew[%2d][%2d]=%02d\n",i,j,objectNew[i][j]->data);
        }
    }
    delete objectNew;

    printf("Objects using NEW version 2===============================\n");
    //notice the triple pointer being assigned a new double pointer array
    myObject** objectNew2 = new myObject* [r];

    for(int i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        //objectNew is a 1D array of double pointers, however if we assign another layer of pointers, it becomes a 2D array of pointers to myObject
        objectNew2[i] = new myObject [c];
        for(int j=0;j<c;j++){
            objectNew2[i][j] = myObject(10*i+j);
            //notice that we dereference data (->)
            printf("objectNew2[%2d][%2d]=%02d\n",i,j,objectNew2[i][j].data);
        }
    }
    delete objectNew2;

    printf("Objects using MALLOC===============================\n");
    //notice the double pointer being allocated double pointers the size of pointers to myObject
    myObject** objectMalloc =(myObject**) malloc(sizeof(myObject*)*r);

    for(int i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        //now we are assigning array of pointers the size of myObject to each double pointer
        objectMalloc[i] = (myObject*) malloc(sizeof(myObject)*c);
        for(int j=0;j<c;j++){
            objectMalloc[i][j] = myObject(10*i+j);
            //notice that we access  data without dereferencing (.)
            printf("objectMalloc[%2d][%2d]=%02d\n",i,j,objectMalloc[i][j].data);
        }
    }
    free((void*) objectMalloc);

    //same as Malloc
    printf("Objects using CALLOC===============================\n");
    myObject** objectCalloc = (myObject**) calloc(r,sizeof(myObject*));

    for(int i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        objectCalloc[i] = (myObject*) calloc(c,sizeof(myObject));
        for(int j=0;j<c;j++){
            objectCalloc[i][j] = myObject(10*i+j);
            printf("objectCalloc[%2d][%2d]=%02d\n",i,j,objectCalloc[i][j].data);
        }
    }
    free((void*) objectCalloc);

    printf("Int using NEW===============================\n");
    //int is not an object
    int** intNew = new int* [r];

    for(int i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        intNew[i] = new int[c];
        for(int j=0;j<c;j++){
            intNew[i][j] = 10*i+j;
            printf("intNew[%2d][%2d]=%02d\n",i,j,intNew[i][j]);
        }
    }
    delete intNew;

    printf("Int using malloc===============================\n");
    int** intMalloc =(int**) malloc(sizeof(int*)*r);

    for(int i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        intMalloc[i] =(int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*c);
        for(int j=0;j<c;j++){
            intMalloc[i][j] = 10*i+j;
            printf("intMalloc[%2d][%2d]=%02d\n",i,j,intMalloc[i][j]);
        }
    }
    free((void*) intMalloc);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `new` and `new[]` are constructor aware, the C memory allocation functions are not.
- Similarly, `delete` and `delete []` are destructor aware, whereas `free` isn't.
- `realloc` does not work with memory allocated with `new`, there is no standards defined analog to the `realloc` function with C++ memory management functions.
- Do not mix `new` and `delete` with `malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc` and `free` (i.e. don't `free` any memory allocated with `new`, don't `delete` any memory allocated with `malloc`)
- If you are doing `new []`, you most likely should be using an `std::vector`, which encapsulates all that memory management for you.
- If you are using memory allocated raw pointers, you might be better served using smart/semi-smart pointers like `boost::shared_ptr` or `boost::scoped_ptr` or `std::auto_ptr`, depending on your needs.
- Thanks to David Thornley for bringing this up:
- Never mix scalar `new` and `delete` with their array forms, i.e. don't `delete[]` memory allocated with `new`, and don't `delete` memory allocated with `new[]`. Undefined behavior all around.
- In your example, you SHOULD use `new` and `new[]` if you must, because as I said, they are constructor aware, and your class is not a [POD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure) data type since it has a constructor.

Please see the C++ FAQ for more information:

- [C++ FAQ Freestore Management](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt)

Comment: Also, match `new` and `delete` together, and `new[]` and `delete[]` together, and remember that you must have one `delete` or `delete []` per `new` or `new[]`.

Comment: I'm assuming that the footprint vector uses is negligible?

Comment: @mna - the memory overhead of `std::vector` is implementation-dependent, but it does have some member variables like a pointer to the allocated block and a member (`std::vector::size_type` which is typedef'd from some integral type) holding the current size of the vector.

Answer (score 2):

> 1) Should I use malloc in c++, or new?
>   If I use new, can I still use realloc?

Use `new`. And never use `realloc` with `new`.

> When should I use realloc? What are
>   the implications of using it in terms
>   of performance and bugs?

Instead of using `realloc`, I usually implement my own memory-pool, from which I reallocate memory when I need it. This also improves performance.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I use malloc in c++, or new? If
>   I use new, can I still use realloc?

You can use `malloc` in C++; however, it is strongly discouraged in most circumstances.  Additionally, if you call `malloc`, `calloc`, `realloc`, etc., you need to use `free` to deallocate the memory when done.

If you use `new` to allocate memory, you must use `delete` to deallocate it.

The C-allocation routines do not have type safety.  `new` does.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write C++ (!!) programs don't use malloc, realloc, free. It is just not C++ functions.

And there is no necessity to use new is your cases (I'm talking about the example).
You should use vector or some other containter.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should try to avoid doing your own memory allocation in C++.  Most (not all) arrays can be done with `std::vector` better than you're going to do your own, particularly since you are making a mistake here.

You allocate, say, `intNew` and `intNew[i]`.  Then you `delete [] intNew;` (the brackets are necessary here, leaving them off is an error), without `delete []`ing any of the `intNew[i]`.  The one-dimensional arrays you allocated are now memory leaks, and cannot possibly be freed because you've lost all references to them.  Neither C nor C++ normally come with a garbage collector.

The C memory allocation functions deal with memory only.  They aren't type-safe, and don't call constructors or destructors.  They can be used with data types that require neither, but you do have to make sure they do neither.  (It is possible to `malloc` memory and use placement `new` to create objects there, but that's more advanced.)

The C++ memory allocation functions deal with memory and objects.  They are type-safe, mostly, and do call constructors and destructors.  Not all objects can be moved safely, so there is no equivalent of `malloc`.  The tricky part is that you have to match `new` with `delete`, and `new[]` with `delete[]`.  You have this error in your code:  `delete intNew;` should be `delete [] intNew;`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Does this mean given the typical 'remove a link from a linked list' found here: http://c-faq.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx8.html, the answer doesn't delete the removed node. Is this a memory leak too?

Comment: @mna:  That depends on how the linked list nodes were created.  It's very common in C to allocate the space for a large number of nodes at once, since it's much more efficient in execution time and memory use than lots and lots of small allocations.  If the nodes are allocated one at a time, then, yes, it's necessary to free the removed node.  If not, then it shouldn't (you can't free just part of what you allocated), but it might be added to a free node list.  The example is simplified, and doesn't take memory allocation into account.